# Create a new instance of a class that is using dependency injection in Aurelia

Tags: dependency-injection, aurelia, aurelia-di

I want to create a factory that is able to create a new instance of a class (MyClass, implementing an abstract class) that is using dependency injection.

I would like the factory to look like this:

### Factory

```
export class Factory {

  public static makeMyClass() {
    return new MyClass();
  }

}
```

However, the EventAggregator is not injected into MyClass when I take this approach.

How can I do this?

### Interface

```
export abstract class MyClassInterface {

  abstract connect();
  abstract disconnect();
  abstract send(message: string);

}
```

### Class

```
@inject(EventAggregator)
export class MyClass {

  constructor(EventAggregator) {}

  connect() {}
  disconnect() {}
  send(message: string) {}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@inject(NewInstance.of(MyClass))` is enough. If you really want to use a factory you have to inject the `EventAggregator` into the factory and then pass it to `MyClass` instance -> `new MyClass(this.eventAggregator);`

Comment: Also, you've named the constructor parameter `EventAggregator`, which is the class name, that might cause issues. I recommend changing that to `eventAggregator` or `ea` or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First Option**

Use the [`NewInstance.of`](http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/dependency-injection#resolvers) resolver:

```
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(NewInstance.of(MyClass))
export class MyViewModel {
   constructor(myClass) {
     this.myClass = myClass; //myClass is always a new instance
   }
}
```

**Second Option**

Use a factory:

```
import {inject, EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(EventAggregator)
export class MyFactory {

  constructor(eventAggregator) {
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
  }

  public static createMyClass() {
    return new MyClass(this.eventAggregator);
  }
}

@inject(MyFactory)
export class MyViewModel {

  constructor(myFactory) {
    this.myClass = myFactory.createMyClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio! Dependency injection is still complicating things for me a little, but I’m starting to understand the principles. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: @martin When using `@inject(NewInstance.of(MyClass))` how do I mock `MyClass` in a test ?

Comment: @Bulkan If you use the aurelia-testing library, you can use the `registerInstance` method on the `aurelia.container` object.  There are several good examples in the documentation http://aurelia.io/docs/testing/components/

Comment: @martin I've tried this and I keep hitting this bug in https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/issues/137 which I haven't been able to find a solution for